# HTML input type number Min Max not working chrome

Tags: php, html, max, min

None of the following codes work for me

```
      <input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="5">  
      <input type="number" name="font-size" min="1" max="32">
```

In my notepad min and max are not colored red, they are just black. I've copied it exactly how I have it.

Using google chrome and everywhere I look this is the format, but it doesn't work for me. Any idea what i could be doing wrong, it's important that I be able to restrict the values. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It works when you try to submit the form. If you want to restrict on real-time, you need to use Javascript.

```
<form action='' method='post'>
    <input type="number" name='n' min="0" max="100" step="5">  
    <input type="number" name="font-size" min="1" max="32">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

[image]

Even the HTML5 input restriction works, you need to check if the input is correct in your PHP code.

```
$error = "";
if ( isset($_POST['n']) && isset($_POST['font-size']) ) {
     if ($_POST['n'] % 5 != 0 || $_POST['n'] < 0 || $_POST['n'] > 100) {
         $error = "Number must be between 0 and 100 and divisible by 5";
     }

     if ($_POST['font-size'] < 1 || $_POST['font-size'] > 32) {
         $error = "Font size must be between 1 and 32";
     }
}

if (empty($error)) {
    // do your logic here
}
```

Then you can show the error in your form

```
<?php echo $error; ?>
<form action='' method='post'>
    <input type="number" name='n' min="0" max="100" step="5">  
    <input type="number" name="font-size" min="1" max="32">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: it doesn't work when i submit the form, I'm using PHP and it lets me input values like 115 120 130+ even after submitting the form. is there a way to restrict in realtime using PHP?